# Namespace / class filtering for TestCafe tests in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, testcafe

I would like to be able to filter the tests in the test tab by the namespace and class as i can do with the suite.

The test case name follows the teamcity test name format with the suite:namespace.class.testcase(parameters)
but it does not get picked up and trying to filter by namespace or class just shows it as no namespace/class.

Is it possible to configure teamcity test tab to pick up and categorize the tests based on the test case name as the tests themselves do not have a namespace/class but I would like to be able to utilize this functionality.

Comment: I can't offer a solution for Teamcity, but you can try to filter tests in TestCafe: [Metadata and Filtering](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403436/guides/intermediate-guides/metadata-and-filtering).